# Unable to run the mandatory command for ingress-nginx setup

Tags: kubernetes, ingress-nginx

I am unable to run the mandatory command for ingress-nginx setup on Google cloud. I have authenticated to Google cloud using 'gcloud auth login'. Next I execute 'kubectl apply -f [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml'](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml%27). I get the error shown below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B4lx.png)

Please help I am stuck

Comment: This is a showstopper. Please help!

Comment: This looks like a connectivity issue to the internet and not an Ingress-nginx issue.  I would check with cURL to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml 

Also, 0.30.0 is a significantly older version.

Answer (score 0):

I executed the steps below and it worked

1. On the Google cloud account, open the cloud shell and navigate to BPB_MEAN_Framework directory in terminal
2. Execute the command gcloud init, reinitialize the cluster, select the account, project and the region
3. Execute the command gcloud container clusters get-credentials blog-dev
4. Execute the command kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.3/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml to configure ingress-nginx